# Create c# exception and not throw it

Tags: c#, exception

Is there a way better than what I'll have written below to get an exception properly set like when thrown?

```
try {
throw new Exception("Blah");
}
catch (Exception exe) {
Assert.NotNull(exe.StackTrace);
DoSomeWork(exe);
// throw;
}
```

Comment: `var myExceptionIDontWantToThrow = new Exception("Blah");`

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? What do you mean by "properly set like when thrown"? What is your end goal?

Comment: What do you mean by properly set? What's your expected output?

Comment: He means that he wants the `StackTrace` but it's `null`. So the real question would be: "how to get stacktrace without throwing an exception"

Comment: What about using [`Environment.StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I mean I want the exception in the same state as if it had been thrown (StackTrace, TargetSite, ...). I want the same result as what the above code does but withouth the ugly try { throw ... } catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is : NO.

The System.Exception properties are filled in [when it is thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default, the stack trace is captured immediately before an exception object is thrown. Use Environment.StackTrace to get stack trace information when no exception is being thrown.

So if you really need an `exception` object in the state it is after being thrown you have no other good way but to throw and catch it.

Still do not drop off the main question: do you really need the exception object?

If you've got a method that has `System.Exception` as an input parameter and you need a StackTrace inside, think of these possible solutions:

1. Method overload with an optional StackTrace input parameter.
2. A successor of System.Exception with a hiding StackTrace property which memorizes the StackTrace when the object is created not thrown.
3. As the last resort you could make an extension method for the System.Exception class which "populates" an instance of the System.Exception:

   ```
   private void MyCode()
   {
       Exception exe = new Exception("Blah");
       exe.Populate();
       DoSomeWork(exe);
   }


   public static void Populate(this System.Exception source)
   {
       try
       {
           throw source;
       }
       catch
       {
       }
   }
   ```